# string replacement in Solaris 11

Tags: regex, sed, awk, pattern-matching, solaris

I have the below output:

```
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: 3412783561b897b8979878c9789798d89789789
 d49a5e3b8ff353844454
id: account 1 0
```

I wish to replace the `Password` field with `Password: *******`

How can I use `sed` to do this for me? I am able to replace the first string, however the following string remains:

```
sed 's/Password: .*/Password: ********/g'
```

Comment: Is there a carriage return in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^Password:/,/^[^ ]/{s/Password: .*/Password: */; /^ /d;}'
```

This looks for lines between one starting with `Password:` and the next line starting with a non-blank and applies the commands between braces to those lines.  For the `Password:` line, it replaces the input with `Password: *` as the question seems to ask for; you can do more complicated substitutions if you want to.  The other command deletes the lines that start with a blank — the continuation lines for the password.  The end-of-range line is left unchanged.

```
$ sed -e '/^Password:/,/^[^ ]/{s/Password: .*/Password: */; /^ /d;}' <<'EOF'
> Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
> Password: 3412783561b897b8979878c9789798d89789789
>  d49a5e3b8ff353844454
> id: account 1 0
> EOF
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: *
id: account 1 0
$
```

I believe this stands a decent chance of working with Solaris `sed`.  If it doesn't work, split the actions over multiple lines:

```
sed -e '/^Password:/,/^[^ ]/{
        s/Password: .*/Password: */
        /^ /d
        }' ...
```

That should definitely work.

Comment: will this work if the file has too many accounts with password field as its reading the file line by line

Comment: just wondering which one runs quicker.. this or the previous one.

Comment: It will work as long as the password line is followed by a non-password line with no blanks at the beginning; it will be pretty robust.  As to speed, there's no difference between the two answers I gave (or, at least, nothing measurable).  I'm not sure which other 'previous one' you might be referring.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` (a bit lengthy but is more generic and will mask passwords spread across multiple lines.)

```
awk 'f&&/:/{print $0;f=0;next}f&&!/:/{gsub(/[^ ]/,"*",$0)}/Password:/{gsub(/./,"*",$2);f=1}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
JS웃$ cat file
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: 3412783561b897b8979878c9789798d89789789
 d49a5e3b8ff353844454
 fadfadf
 agww2342342
id: account 1 0

JS웃$ awk 'f&&/:/{print $0;f=0;next}f&&!/:/{gsub(/[^ ]/,"*",$0)}/Password:/{gsub(/./,"*",$2);f=1}1' file
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: ***************************************
 ********************
 *******
 ***********
id: account 1 0
```

#### Update:

```
awk 'f&&/:/{print $0;f=0;next}f&&!/:/{next}/Password:/{gsub(/.*/,"*********",$2);f=1}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
[JS웃:~/Temp]$ awk 'f&&/:/{print $0;f=0;next}f&&!/:/{next}/Password:/{gsub(/.*/,"*********",$2);f=1}1' file
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: *********
id: account 1 0
```

Comment: i get an error "awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1"

Comment: Try using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `nawk` as Solaris `awk` is buggy

Comment: thanks your solution works. i like this but the password field seems to be a bit too long. is possible to cut it short anyway ? shows too many astericks

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU sed, assuming there is no line break in your string and one asterisk for every pwd character:

---

```
$cat file
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au Password: 3412783561b897b8979878c9789798d89789789d49a5e3b8ff353844454 id: account 1 0
$sed -r 's/\b[0-9_a-f]\B/*/5;:k;s/\*\w/**/;tk' file
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au Password: *********************************************************** id: account 1 0
```

This maybe doesn't work on solaris11 systems by default.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
sed 's/^\(Password: \).*/\1*/g' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: 3412783561b897b8979878c9789798d89789789
 d49a5e3b8ff353844454
id: account 1 0
>
> sed 's/^\(Password: \).*/\1*/g' temp
Profile: id=standard,ou=groups,ou=access,ou=data,o=abc,c=au
Password: *
 d49a5e3b8ff353844454
id: account 1 0
>
```